# JavaScript geolocation: check distance from 2 gps coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, gps

I have two constants - gps lalitude and longtitude. I get user position by HTML5 JS API. `getCurrentPosition()` method provide `coords.accuracy` which show me accuracy of position.
I need check if distance from gps coords in constants and `getCurrentPosition()` is smaller about 10 meters.

Is there any library or jQuery plugin or I must write it itself?

Comment: I found these working codes: https://github.com/jdjkelly/jQuery-haversine/blob/master/jquery.haversine.0.2.js and  https://github.com/janantala/GPS-distance/blob/master/javascript/distance.js
 What is better?

Answer (score 0):

The code below is what I use with Google Maps API v3. Perhaps you can do something similar with your libraries. The haversine formula's take into account the globe is a sphere which is my best bet to calculate distances. Google API comes with an extra [library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) to do this.

Usually you find your libraries to calculate distances and you come up with your own logic.
So again, take from this logic what you need and try out the libraries you've found.

```
orderMarkersByDistance: function (markers) {
    var flex = this,
        geodesic = [],
        arrClosest = [],
        to, distance, arrDistances,
        map = this.root.gmap3("get");

    // loop through markers and calculate their distances from the center
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        to = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng);
        distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(map.center, to);
        geodesic.push([i, distance]);
    }

    // sort the distances
    geodesic.sort(function (a, b) { return a[1] - b[1]; });

    // optionally, take the closest distances
    arrDistances = geodesic.slice(0, 3);

    // return closest markers
    $.each(arrDistances, function (idx, item) {
        arrClosest.push(markers[item[0]]);
    });

    return arrClosest;
},
```

Comment: It looks good, but you need Internet connection. I want offline (mobile) app.

Comment: Ah it's like that, might want to add that to your question as that wasn't clear to me.